# Having an issue with trimming a string in C#

Tags: c#, trim

I have a problem about trimming below word in C#

For example, I got a string = "StackLevelTwoItem" and I need to pull the "Two" or "Three"  out of this string.

StackLevelTwoItem           -> I should get "**Two**"
StackLevelThreeItem         -> I should get "**Three**"

... and so on ...

Can anybody help?

Thank you

Comment: Do you have any pattern? Your string is always as `StackLevelXXXItem` format?

Comment: Let's see your attempts

Comment: Try using a pattern like `^StackLevel[.*]Item$` with regular expression in order to get the result you want.

Answer (score 2):

For the two examples given:

```
const string prefix = "StackLevel";
const string suffix = "Item";

public static string GetCentralPart(string str)
{
    if (str == null)
    {
        return str;
    }

    if (!str.StartsWith(prefix) || !str.EndsWith(suffix))
    {
        return str;
    }

    return str.Substring(prefix.Length, str.Length - prefix.Length - suffix.Length);
}
```

Use:

```
string str = "StackLevelThreeItem";
string centralPart = GetCentralPart(str);
```

The code is quite linear... The only interesting points are the use of some `const string` for the prefix/suffix, the use of `StartsWith`/`EndsWith` to check that the string really has the prefix/suffix, and how the `Substring` length is calculated.

Answer (score 0):

i would use RegEx for this Case

```
string Result = Regex.Match("StackLevelOneItem", @"(?<=StackLevel)[\w]*(?=Item)").Value;
```

Comment: I tried this solution and it worked perfect. Thank you so much fubo, Anton Kedrov and xanatos for genuinely being helpful. Also, I would like to comment about "Soner Gönül" marking my question as duplicate adn addressing to a totally irrelevant link. The link he point is about pulling a word from a big sentence. My case here is different. Hope he can see this comment and rewind what he did was wrong!

Comment: @ms_jordan - great! if you like, you can accept my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using Regex.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var l2 = GetLevel("StackLevelTwoItem");     // returns "Two"
    var l3 = GetLevel("StackLevelThreeItem");   // returns "Three"
    var l1 = GetLevel("StackLvlOneItem");       // returns empty string
}

static string GetLevel(string input)
{
    var pattern = "StackLevel(.*)Item";
    var match = Regex.Match(input, pattern);

    if (match.Groups[1].Success)
        return match.Groups[1].Value;
    else
        return String.Empty;
}
```